# Vertical align of text HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, valign

I see that many people ask this there, but I didn't found solution for my problem in given answers.

I have very simple situation there.

`<div id="tooltipDesc">
<span id="longDesc">Lorem ipsum</span>
</div>`

I need text to be verticaly aligned to the middle od div.

This is my recent CSS:

```
#tooltipDesc{
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 color: #6c6c6c;
 border: 1px black solid;
}

#longDesc{
  color: #6c6c6c;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 280px;
  height: 78px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: There are so very, very, very many duplicates of this exact question -- if you're going to post another you really need to explain why one of those solutions isn't working for you.

Comment: @daniel beck agreed i have seen several in the past month alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with flexbox, or with absolute text positioning. Personally I prefer to use flexbox, with the following:

```
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
```

[Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4cev8bp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add line-height, like this:

```
#longDesc{
  color: #6c6c6c;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 280px;
  height: 78px;
  line-height: 78px;
}
```

Comment: It is good when I have one line inside span, but if I have more second line goes outside of parent div..

Answer (score 0):

If it's just text use:

html:

```
<p class= "example"; > Lorem ipsum  </p>
```

css:

```
.example{
  text-align: center;
}
```

useful link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Answer (score 0):

change in in`longDesc div` the value of property`text-align` to `center` , then add the following `position:absolute; top:35%;` finaly make a change in `tooltipDesc position:relative` as illustrated below.

```
#tooltipDesc{
 position: relative;  /* has been changed */
 width: 300px;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 color: #6c6c6c;
 border: 1px black solid;
}

#longDesc{
 position:absolute; /* has been added */
 color: #6c6c6c;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center; /* has been changed */
 top:35%;  /* has been added */
 line-height: normal;
 width: 280px;
 height: 78px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

See in action: https://jsfiddle.net/ex5gww6y/2/